Unable to resolve service Laminas MVC Cache Storage
Unable to Resolve Service:
How does one resolve a service via a /conf/autoload/local.php config file.
Error:

Fatal error: Uncaught
Laminas\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Unable to
resolve service "Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memory"to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration? in /var/www/vhosts/.../portal/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:586

This issue came about while updating to PHP8.2 and using composer.
The application runs fine on php7.4...
I've tried using docs https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-cache/v4/storage/adapter/ but not really a clear set of instructions for config initialisation.
I cannot figure out why this requirement has suddenly appeared.
UPDATE:
The issue was a combination of version conflicts and incorrect configuration options.
Required this: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-cache/v3/application-integration/usage-in-a-laminas-mvc-application/ for global.php config setup.

Additions to Module.php solved the initial problem

'default-cache' setting in config resolved the secondary issue
'Laminas\Cache',
'Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memory',
'Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem',


and
'caches' => [
        'default-cache' => [
            'adapter' => Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem::class,
            'options' => [
                'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../data/cache',
            ],
        ],
    ],

Thanks to @Ermenegildo

Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Composer itself? Which version of laminas/laminas-cache are you using? The last one that supported PHP 7.4 is v3.6.0, but that one is not compatible with PHP 8.2, so maybe you need to update it?

v: "laminas/laminas-cache" : "^3.12.2" - thanks, it's close...

In your config/modules.config.php file, check that the following modules are enabled:
return [
    // ...
    'Laminas\Cache',
    'Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memory',
    // ...
];

Considering the error message you get, I think you enabled only the first one.
If the configuration cache is enabled, don't forget to clear it.

Thank you. This resolved the namespace / finding the class. No a separate issue "Service with name "FilesystemCache" could not be created. Reason: Configuration must contain a "adapter" key." ... BUT thank you, your solution resolved the initial problem. Once I get it all I'll mark as correct. (specifically adding the .../Adapter/Memory module.

@JI-Web for the second error, I think you should add the Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Filesystem module to the list (I have always these 3 actives, but not always using the filesystem one)
